# Wordpress configuration on live server showing error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made some configuration in wordpress themes and plugins. It worked fine in localhost. After that I just uploaded the files to wordpress(Plugins and themes). After that in search field when I tried to search something it showed an error like

`Warning: include_once(wp-load.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/foledrname/public_html/clients/london/wp-content/plugins/wp-easybooking/widgets/ajaxProposeLocation.php on line 15`.

In localhost all the things are working just perfect. So can someone kindly tell me whats the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

it seems on page ajaxProposeLocation.php where you are loading wp-load.php with include statement its path is wrong 
you should not include wp-load.php in wp plugin becoz Both the plugin directory and the wp-content directory can be moved around in the installation. ALL the WordPress files could be moved about in this manner, are you going to search around for them?

You’ve just doubled the load on that server. WordPress and the PHP processing of it all now have to get loaded twice for every page load.

may i ask why you are loading wp-load.php ?